# How does .NET Framework Determine Zones?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I got the following error but am perplexed why .NET thinks this DLL is located in the internet zone when clearly it is on the Intranet. Any ideas?

### Here is the error NUNIT is throwing:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: 
The type initializer for 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.   
at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner..cctor()

The action that failed was:
LinkDemand

The assembly or AppDomain that failed was:
nunit-console-runner, Version=2.5.7.10213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77

The method that caused the failure was:
NUnit.Core.Logger GetLogger(System.Type)

The Zone of the assembly that failed was:
Internet

The Url of the assembly that failed was:
file://fs1/pc/Tools/dlls/NUnit/NUnit/bin/net-2.0/lib/nunit-console-runner.DLL   

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---   
at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)   
at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Class1.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows "remembers" where a file came from.

If I understand the error correctly it is the Nunit dll that was downloaded from the internet that is failing.

Go into windows explorer, select properties on this file. At the bottom of the general tab there should be a button that you can press to confirm that it is safe.